# ViewTreeObserver.OnWindowFocusChangeListener in a service

Tags: java, android, android-viewtreeobserver, android-window

How to implement ViewTreeObserver.OnWindowFocusChangeListener in a service in Android . The code does not show any type of error when i use it in my java file .
Is there any other way to use OnWindowFocusChangeListener in a service ?
Please help me.
Thanks in advance !!

Comment: services dont have any UI, so what `View` do you want to observe with `ViewTreeObserver`?

Comment: @pskink yes i agree . But, is there a way to make service detect what the user does in screen ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Do it like this way

```
WindowManager windowManager=(WindowManager)getSystemService(WINDOW_SERVICE);
LayoutInflater inflater= 
(LayoutInflater)getSystemService(LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
RelativeLayout layout=(RelativeLayout) inflater.inflate(R.layout.box,null);
```

You need a WindowManager.LayoutParams object which should contain the parameters for the layout

```
windowManager.addView(layout,params);
```

now add ViewTreeObserver.OnWindowFocusChangeListener on your desired view.

Comment: can this be applied to a service ?

Comment: what should my params be? TYPE_SYSTEM_ALERT ??

Comment: You need a WindowManager.LayoutParams object which should contain the parameters for the layout

Comment: that's great, m happy i was helpful, happy coding :) Please upvote my answer